# SAGE ODBC driver - minimum required folder permisions

Tags: permissions, security, odbc

I have a website which I want to connect to SAGE ACCDATA folder (which resides on a different server but same network to the intranet server) using their proprietary ODBC driver.

For security purposes I'm trying to find out the minimum folder permissions that are required in order to allow this connection.

If I give the folder 'Everyone' permission the connection works regardless of the application pool identity, similarly if I give the folder the 'Network' security principal/SID (A group that includes all users who are signed in via a network connection.) the connection works regardless of application pool identity.

I can't seem to find this documented anywhere, indeed the only documentation I can find about ODBC says to give it 'Everyone', nothing that mentions 'Network'!

P.S. I know I should leave admin as a permission, that is fine, I want to lock down the actual ODBC required permission to just read the data.

Comment: "*the actual ODBC required permission*" - This is a little confusing because ODBC doesn't require permissions, the network and whatever is being done through the ODBC driver is what determines what permissions are needed. Presumably you're using an account to connect to the folder through the ODBC driver, somewhere in the stack. That account is what you need to grant permissions to, for the folder. Note this isn't really a database question and probably should be asked on a different forum like [Network Engineering](https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @J.D. I started off by stating that it concerns a website and so IIS. Anyone that knows SAGE would know you can only READ through their ODBC. I use an account to connect in SAGE's proprietary ODBC driver which is the SAGE system admin, defined in SAGE, nothing to do with windows, there is no windows user account etc for it. Open Database Connectivity... ODBC. It is not a network issue, it is a SAGE ODBC driver issue.

Comment: The account used in IIS for the website that operates through the ODBC driver to access the folder is likely what you need to provision access to. Folder permissions provisioning is always a network issue. Regardless, again, this is not a database issue.

Comment: @PaulZahra, I've found Sage's ODBC driver is archaic and doesn't play nice with Windows' permissions system. I suspect it also requires read/write access in order to manage concurrent transactional access to the data, even if the ODBC driver will not modify data.

Comment: @Steve Yup archaic for sure... I've since spoken to a SAGE dev and they said their ODBC driver is based around Excels ODBC! LOL... and because of the convoluted way that SAGE interconnects with other aspects of itself, if you restrict folder permissions it can do strange things like slow down SAGE, cause 'company' data corruption or strange issues that look like file locks but aren't... and so they recommend giving 'Everyone' permission! Funnily enough they won't document it though!

Comment: @J.D. If only... the app pool runs under Network Service, give Network Service full folder permission and it won't work, If I give it Network or Everyone permission then it works. Nope it's a SAGE ODBC driver issue not working well with windows permissions, see my answer to the post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll leave this here should anyone else encounter issues with SAGE ODBC driver.

**Answer:** Since posting this question I've spoken to a SAGE dev.

Basically because of the way that SAGE interconnects with other aspects of itself, if you restrict folder permissions to just the DB files (Like I wanted to restrict it to just the companies ACCDATA folder) it can do strange things like slow down SAGE, cause 'company' data corruption or strange issues that look like file locks but aren't... and so they recommend giving 'Everyone' permission!